# Isometric view for games in Kivy

Tags: python, kivy, isometric

I am having some trouble rendering an isometric game in Kivy.

In Pygame, I successfully got this code to run:

```
for row in map_data:
    for tile in row:
        cartx = currentTile * tileWidth    #x is the index of the currentTile * the tile width
        carty = currentRow * tileHeight     #y is the index of the currentRow * the tile height

        x = WIN_WIDTH_HALF + (cartx - carty) / 2
        print(x)
        y = WIN_HEIGHT_QUARTER + (cartx + carty) / 4
        print(y)
        print('\n')

        if tile == 1:
            tileImage = wall
        else:
            tileImage = grass

        DISPLAYSURF.blit(tileImage, (x, y)) #display the actual tile
        currentTile += 1
    currentTile = 0
    currentRow += 1
```

But now, having been playing around in Kivy and wanting to make a simple isometric game in it too, I'm struggling to think of how to represent the above in the Kv design language.

I am new to Kivy and admittedly still find to grasp the connection between a *.py and *.kv file, as in what goes where, so any advice will be appreciated. Basically, I need the same functionality as the above code gives but running seamlessly in Kivy.

Thanks in advance,
Ilmiont

Comment: You should read the documentation and tutorial for Kivy then, both of which are robust enough to enable you to start off and understand the basics.

Comment: The direct (and low level) equivalent is to add a series of Rectangles to the canvas, each with the relevant position, size and image source. A higher level kivy solution would be to add Image widgets to a layout. If you're stuck with something specific, explain that problem, but otherwise read about these things and try it.